# Journal: which services are filling up the allowed journal-size?

Tags: systemd-journald

On a Debian machine, by default the `systemd-journal` is caring about the logs.

It's configuration limits the max disk space it can use:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/journald.conf
SystemMaxUse=100M
SystemKeepFree=200M
```

Now its directory is filled up to around 100M:

```
$ du -hs /var/log/journal
109M    /var/log/journal
```

Inside the *journal* directory, there is only one single directory with many binary files inside.

Is there a way to know the distribution of this 109M space by services?

I.e.

```
nginx: 15M
httpd: 20M
...
```

Currently I didn't found any way to check this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but only by going through all entries in your journal manually, using the `sd-journal` C API. It's not complicated, and copying together an example, some of it from bits and pieces from the [`sd_journal_next` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_journal_next.html#) and replacing `_get_data` with `_enumerate_data`:

I put the source code [here](https://gist.github.com/marcusmueller/657e28d2b7a82428f2ed17f40cfcefe2#file-journalsizes-c). **This is a bit quick&dirty, the `sd_*` documentation is really not that good, so here's to hoping things are correct:

```c
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPLv3 */
/* Copyright 2023 Marcus Müller
 * Somewhat based on man sd_journal_get_data (MIT-0), but most of the original work by
 * Marcus Müller
 */

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <systemd/sd-journal.h>

const char* KEY = "_SYSTEMD_UNIT=";
const char* ALTKEY = "_TRANSPORT=";
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int r;
    size_t KEYLEN = strlen(KEY);
    size_t ALTKEYLEN = strlen(ALTKEY);
    sd_journal* j;
    r = sd_journal_open(&j, SD_JOURNAL_LOCAL_ONLY);
    if (r < 0) {
        errno = -r;
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open journal: %m\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* Print header */
    puts("unit name;length\n");

    SD_JOURNAL_FOREACH(j)
    {
        const char* data_ptr;
        size_t field_length;
        size_t total_length = 0;
        char* unitname = NULL;
        size_t unitname_len = 0;
        int unit_found = 0;

        while (0 < sd_journal_enumerate_data(j, (const void**)&data_ptr, &field_length)) {
            /* We just break the counting if we encounter a broken entry. */
            total_length += field_length;
            if (unit_found == 0) {
                if (field_length > KEYLEN && strncmp(data_ptr, KEY, KEYLEN) == 0) {
                    unit_found = 1;
                    unitname_len = field_length - KEYLEN;
                    unitname = realloc(unitname, unitname_len);
                    strncpy(unitname, data_ptr + KEYLEN, unitname_len);
                } else if (field_length > ALTKEYLEN && (unitname_len == 0) &&
                           strncmp(data_ptr, ALTKEY, ALTKEYLEN) == 0) {
                    unitname_len = field_length - ALTKEYLEN;
                    unitname = realloc(unitname, unitname_len);
                    strncpy(unitname, data_ptr + ALTKEYLEN, unitname_len);
                }
            }
        }

        if (unitname_len == 0) {
            printf("UNKNOWN;%zu\n", total_length);
        } else {
            printf("%*s;%zu\n", (int)unitname_len, unitname, total_length);
            free(unitname);
        }
    }
    sd_journal_close(j);
    return 0;
}
```

save as `journalsizes.c`, compile with

```bash
c99 -o journalsizes $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libsystemd) journalsizes.c
```

and run by `./journalsizes` to get a semicolon-separated list of unit names ; log entry lengths in bytes.

You can use that, for example, by putting into a text file called [accumulate_logsizes.sql](https://gist.github.com/marcusmueller/657e28d2b7a82428f2ed17f40cfcefe2#file-accumulate_logsizes-sql) the following:

```sql
.mode csv
.separator ;
.import "|./journalsizes" journal
SELECT
  "unit name",
  SUM("length")/(1024*1024.0) AS megabyte
FROM
  journal
GROUP BY
  "unit name"
ORDER BY
  megabyte
DESC LIMIT 10;
```

and running that through `sqlite3`:

```bash
sqlite3 < accumulate_logsizes.sql
```

Comment: Compile line complains about "undefined reference to `sd_journal_open'". I compiled it with `gcc -o journalsizes journalsizes.c -lsystemd` and it compiles successfully.

Comment: sqlite3 command is better with `sqlite3 < accumulate_logsizes.sql 2>/dev/null` to hide warnings like this: "*<pipe>:2: expected 2 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL*"

Comment: and one more slight mod: `.mode column` into the sql to get better display. Otherwise this is perfect, I appreciate this.